# how to override delete confirmation page in django admin site?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In my django 1.4 project I have a requirement to override the delete confirmation page in admin site and also perform some additional task model.I found generic DeleteView, but not found any good help about how to use it.

Answer (score 4):

To override admin default confirmation page, define your own  `admin/delete_confirmation.html` ([source on Github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html)) template. For example: if you want to override confirmation page for model `Book` defined in the app `Library`, create file `TEMPLATES_ROOT_DIRECTORY/admin/library/book/delete_confirmation.html`.

```
{% extends "admin/delete_confirmation.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
    </p>

    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

To modify view, define/override `ModelAdmin.delete_view(...)` on your admin subclass. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.delete_view.

Comment: For those who would like to take a [look](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.4/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1826-L1886) at the [view](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.4/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1455-L1474). Well, and the [template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1.4/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html).

Answer (score 2):

To override an external app view, just override the url. See [How to override a view from an external Django app](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/19777151073/how-to-override-a-view-from-an-external-django-app).