# Delete Button on "Delete Confirmation" Page of Django Admin Is not Working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin

Here is my template path

```
project/templates/app_name/delete_confirmation.html

{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls %}


{% block content %}
{% if perms_lacking %}
   <p>{% blocktrans with escaped_object=object %}Deleting the {{ object_name }} '{{ escaped_object }}' would result in deleting related objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the following types of objects:{% endblocktrans %}</p>
   <ul>
   {% for obj in perms_lacking %}
    <li>{{ obj }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% elif protected %}
    <p>{% blocktrans with escaped_object=object %}Deleting the {{ object_name }} '{{ escaped_object }}' would require deleting the following protected related objects:{% endblocktrans %}</p>
   <ul>
   {% for obj in protected %}
       <li>{{ obj }}</li>
   {% endfor %}
   </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>{% blocktrans with escaped_object=object %}Are you sure you want to delete the {{ object_name }} "{{ escaped_object }}"? All of the following related items will be deleted:{% endblocktrans %}</p>
    {% include "admin/includes/object_delete_summary.html" %}
    <h2>{% trans "Objects" %}</h2>
    <ul>{{ deleted_objects|unordered_list }}</ul>
    <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="yes" />
    {% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ is_popup_var }}" value="1" />{% endif %}
    {% if to_field %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ to_field_var }}" value="{{ to_field }}" />{% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Yes, I'm sure" %}" />
    <a href="#" onclick="window.history.back(); return false;" class="button cancel-link">{% trans "No, take me back" %}</a>
    </div>
    </form>
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans "Cancel" %}" onclick="window.history.back(); return false;"/>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm here trying to inherit django-admin's `delete_confirmation.html` template. I want to add a `cancel` button at the time of deleting the objects in an app. It shows me cancel button and it also works fine but `delete` button does nothing by doing so.

I've tried to add links in my "local template" which are defined in "admin template" but it raised error that "reverse url not found". Is there any workaround to do that? Please suggest me the right way to do it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Good answer how to override the delete confimration page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440732/how-to-override-delete-confirmation-page-in-django-admin-site

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to override delete confirmation page in django admin site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440732/how-to-override-delete-confirmation-page-in-django-admin-site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of inheriting django-admin's delete-confirmation.html template copy the template from *django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/delete_confirmation.html* to your project directory and do the changes there itself.